# How can we modify size of Badge in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

Not able to modify radius of Badge in jetpack compose as Radius and Shape are given internally not able to modify it

Comment: You can't modify it, since it uses `BadgeWithContentRadius = 8.dp` to draw `RoundedCornerShape(radius)` but you can write your own implementation or check [this library](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Badge) if you want to have a badge with more customization.

Comment: Can you help me get the implementation for build.gradle(app)

Comment: It's not a library that is published because of that  you need to copy in lib module and add it to your project. It's easy to implement though. Check the demos, it will give you the idea.

Comment: Also i don't think this question  needs more clarity. It's asking how you can change radius of `androidx.compose.material.Badge`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the radius of the shape, but you can change the size of the `Badge` using the `size` modifier.

Something like:

```
BadgedBox(
    badge = { 
        Badge(
          modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp)
        ){
          Text( "9",fontSize= 14.sp) }
    }
)
```

Custom size:
[image]

Default:
[image]

Comment: Need radius only.

Comment: @sarthakgupta Then you have to write your own implementation